# Spring cloud data flow deployment

Tags: deployment, spring-cloud-dataflow

I wanna deploy the Spring-cloud-data-flow on several hosts. 
I will deploy the server of Spring-cloud-data-flow on one host-A, and deploy the agents on the other hosts(These hosts are in charge of executing the tasks).
Except the host-A, all the other hosts run the same tasks.
Shall I modify on the basis of the Spring Cloud Data Flow Local Server or on the Spring Cloud Data Flow Apache Yarn Server or other better choice?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean how the apps are deployed on several hosts? If so, the apps are deployed using the underlying `deployer` implementation. For instance, if it is `local` deployer then, each app is deployed by spawning a new process. You can scale out the number apps deployment using the `count` property during the stream `deploy`. I am not sure what do you mean by the agents here.